# Any possible way to use fixed and multiple function argument types in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, testing

I'm trying to write some tests for API in Kotlin. At my case API-endpoint accepts both (String and Int) type for body JSON fields, so i want use them both in different cases. I want to find any advice for using it something like that `val myVal: Any in (String, Int)`.

I know some possible ways, but i think it is a bud solutions:

1. Use `Any` type - seems unsafe, i need to restrict it to only needable types.
2. Redefine function with other argument types - some of my API-endpoints can have many parameters like that

Some example:

```
fun main() {
    
    fun myRequestMethod(
        firstParam: Any, //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
        secondParam: Any, //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
        thirdParam: Any //actualy can be ONLY String or Int
    ) {
        //do api-request
        println("$firstParam, $secondParam, $thirdParam")
    }
    
    myRequestMethod(1, 2, 3) //acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod("1", 2, "3") //acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod(mapOf("1" to 1), listOf(2, 2, 2), "3") //NOT acceptible with Any type
    myRequestMethod(1, listOf(1, 2, 3), mapOf("1" to 1)) //NOT acceptible with Any type
}
```

I tried to use `Any` type and redefine my function

Comment: You need to check in , out and where in kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to express union types in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755843/how-to-express-union-types-in-kotlin)

Comment: @Sam, Either don't work clearly as i want

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani too hard for me, how use it at my example?

Comment: @BrainDrill Why Either doesn't fit your needs? This is probably the best choice in your case, because you have multiple such params.

Comment: Also, are these params converted to strings as in your example? If yes, couldn't you simply receive strings? There isn't a big added value in receiving ints.

Comment: @broot how to use `Either` in my case? If i setup function argument like `myArgument: Either<String, Int>` i cant just call this function like `myFunc(1)` or `myFunc("1")`

Comment: @BrainDrill This is correct, by using `Either` you can't pass arguments directly. What you asked is simply not supported on Kotlin and your only options are either make your code weakly typed or pass arguments wrapped in some additional type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really feels like an XY problem, i.e. my strong suggestion is that you think if there is a better approach that doesn't require union types.

However if you need to do this in Kotlin, you could do something like this:

```
sealed interface UnionIntString {
    val value: Any

    @JvmInline
    value class UnionInt(override val value: Int) : UnionIntString

    @JvmInline
    value class UnionString(override val value: String) : UnionIntString
}

typealias UIS = UnionIntString
typealias UI = UnionIntString.UnionInt
typealias US = UnionIntString.UnionString

val Int.u: UI get() = UI(this)

val String.u: US get() = US(this)

object Example {

    private fun makeRequest(a: UIS, b: UIS) {
        when (a) {
            is UI -> println(a.value)
            is US -> println(b.value)
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        makeRequest(12.u, "hello".u)
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

Start off with a Sealed interface that provides two cases (Int or String).

Declare a value property at the top level so we can directly access the value without needing to identify the child class.

We can use value classes since we are only wrapping single values in each case.

Since this is for tests and we don't want to do a lot of typing in the Tests we will (type) alias the names to shorter values.

Next we define extension functions for Int and String.

The `makeRequest()` method declares the parameters as `UIS`.
Inside this method we can use a `when()` clause if we care about the type of the variable or just access the `value : Any` property directly.

Finally when we call the method we just suffix the values with `.u` to invoke the extension functions.